# Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0

Tags: angularjs, json, ionic-framework

I want to insert a data to MYSQL using IONIC AngularJS. But i got error "Unexpected token o in JSON at position 0"

this is my controller from app.php

```
app.controller('BookingCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
$scope.bookingSave = function(){
     $http({
      method: 'post',
      url: "http://localhost/test/insertDB.php",
      data: {
                'name' : $scope.nameuser,
                'email' : $scope.email,
                'phone': $scope.phone,
                'type' : 'save_user' 
            },
      headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .success(function(data,status,headers,config){
        console.log("Data Inserted Successfully");
    })
    }
});
```

then this is the insertDB.php

```
require_once 'conn.php';
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));

$name = $conn->real_escape_string($data->nameuser);
$email = $conn->real_escape_string($data->email);
$phone = $conn->real_escape_string($data->phone);
```

Please help me

Comment: The client tells PHP that the body is of type 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' instead of the default application/json. , although what you're sending is in fact JSON, and the PHP script expects JSON. Why did you add this header? Also, post the exact and complete error/stack trace. And tell wehere it happens (server-side, client-side?)

Comment: i change the headers content-type to 'application/json' but the server-side showing error Undefined property: stdClass::$nameuser in C:\xampp\htdocs\test\insertDB.php on line 7

Comment: Well, the JSON you're sending indeed doesn't have any `nameuser` field. It has a `name` field, though.

Comment: this is my booking_form.html

<input type="text" ng-model='nameuser' name='nameuser' placeholder="Username">



then, this is my route

.state('tabs.booking', {
      url: '/booking',
      views: {
        'booking-tab': {
          templateUrl: 'templates/booking_form.html',
    controller: 'BookingCtrl'
        }
      }
    })

Comment: Form is irrelevant... it's the property names of `data` object that will be accessed in php.

Comment: its worked, i change the input text to <input type="text" ng-model='booking.nameuser'  placeholder="Username">,, then change the property `data` to 'name' : $scope.booking.nameuser

Comment: thanks for your help :)